# Reminder functionlity in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am developing windows phone 7 application.how to set reminder functionality in 7.0?

can we set reminder functionality in 7.0.i saw some articles that only supported in 7.1.
but my application was in 7.0.How to do?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your application to 7.1?

Comment: No,my app need to support all versions.please tell me reminder functionality in windows phone 7.....

Comment: Why does it need to support all versions? All generation 1 devices have had upgrades to 7.1 made available, and all new devices will have 7.1 by default so there is little reason to support 7.0.

Comment: In my apps, I am seeing less than 10% of the people running/downloading 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reminder functionality available in 7.0